# Why no colors in bokeh plot's legend

Tags: python, colors, legend, bokeh

In Bokeh 0.12.2, I was able to make a stacked bar chart with various hover tooltips using plotting and VBars. I also enabled a legend for the plot. However, my vbars are colored and the colors for each vbar (each stack) are not appearing in the legend. Only the names for the stack in the legend are appearing. Is this not an implemented feature yet or a bug maybe? Or maybe I'm missing something?

[what my chart looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJCzC.png)

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a bug in the bokeh source code which is being fixed if not fixed already.